# Does $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}dx$ diverge, converge, or absolutely converge?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm given this integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}dx
$$
I need to tell if this integral diverges, converges or absolutely converges

My efforts:

Because $0$ causes problems, split the integral like
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}dx \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}dx.
$$

For the integral $1$ to $\infty$:
$$
f(x)=1-e^{-x},g(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}
$$
and using Dirichlet test, is it possible?

and for the integral $0$ to $1$, use comparison test, and choose $g(x)$ as
$$ 
g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Don't know about Dirichlet's test, but in $\int_1^\infty...$ you can notice that the integrand is limited by $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$, and the latter can be evaluated directly by replacing $x = u^2$.

Comment: oh good idea i`l try that soon ,thank you

Comment: There is no problem at $x=0$ since the integrand is $\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the integrand is non-negative so there's no need to investigate absolute convergence separately. We have for $x>0$:
$$0\leq \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\\
0\leq \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} $$
The second inequality follows from $1-e^{-x}\leq 1$. The first one follows from $e^{t}\geq t+1$ with $t=-x$ which gives us $1-e^{-x}\leq x$. Finally, since the integrals $\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge, we can conclude that the two integrals you mentioned also converge.

Regarding your question about Dirichlet's test, with this choice of functions, we'd need the antiderivative $F(x)=\int_1^x\left(1-e^{-t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$ to be uniformly bounded for $x\ge 1$, but $F(x)=x+e^{-x}-(1+e^{-1})$ is clearly unbounded as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: thank you and everybody for the quick response,you helped a lot